# QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: php, quickbooks, mysql-error-1068

I am using Quickbook Premier 2010(Desktop version). It’s working well with my ERP application at my local system. Now I am focusing to connect Quickbook with ERP application which is hosted on Remote server. In this case, I am getting the following error when I try to update selected.

> Version: Not provided by service  Message: Authentication failed
>
> Description: QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error
>   message. Client found response content type of 'text/html', but
>   expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with the error message: --

```
<br /> <b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>E:\xampp3\htdocs\Missisystem\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysql.php</b> on line <b>289</b><br /> <br />

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Error Num.: 1068 Error Msg.:Multiple primary key defined SQL: ALTER TABLE quickbooks_log ADD PRIMARY KEY(quickbooks_log_id);  in <b>E:\xampp3\htdocs\Missisystem\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysql.php</b> on line <b>382</b><br />  --.
```

> See QWCLog for more details. Remember to turn logging on.

Help me to clear this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue:

`<br /> <b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>E:\xampp3\htdocs\Missisystem\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysql.php</b> on line <b>289</b><br /> <br />`

You can change your `$dsn` string to be:

```
$dsn = 'mysqli://...
```

Instead of:

```
$dsn = 'mysql://...
```

To fix this issue:

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Error Num.: 1068 Error Msg.:Multiple primary key defined SQL: ALTER TABLE quickbooks_log ADD PRIMARY KEY(quickbooks_log_id);  in <b>E:\xampp3\htdocs\Missisystem\quickbooks\QuickBooks\Driver\Sql\Mysql.php</b> on line <b>382</b><br />  --.`

You should check your quickbooks_log SQL table and see if there's a primary key defined or not. If you can't figure it out, try dropping all of the `quickbooks_*` tables and letting the code re-create them.